# How to set fontsize in percent in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript

Good morning, I'm trying to make a text editor and to change the font using this procedure:

```js
function Select_(selectname, selectname_cor) {
  var cursel = document.getElementById(selectname).selectedIndex;
  if (cursel != 0) {
    var selected = document.getElementById(selectname).options[cursel].value;
    if (selectname_cor == "fontsize") {
      sel = window.getSelection();
      document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<font style='font-size:" + selected + "%;'>" + sel + "</font>");
    }
    document.getElementById(selectname).selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("edit").focus();
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Documento senza titolo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
  <select unselectable="on" id="fontsize" onchange="Select_(this.id,'fontsize');">
    <option selected="selected" value="Size">Size</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
  </select>
  <div id="edit" style="background:#FFFFCC; height:200px;" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But I get different results: in firefox I get:

```
<font style="font-size:140%;">aaaa<font style="font-size:100%;">bbbb</font></font>
```

in chrome I get:

```
<font style="font-size:140%;">aaaa</font><font style="font-size:100%;">bbbb</font>
```

How can I get the result of chrome with firefox?

Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!Thanks!

Comment: do not use font tags.... It has been obsolete for ages

Comment: What steps did you take to get that?

Comment: ciao, Do you speak italian?

Comment: I'm building a text editor and I need the user to change the font size. To do this I use the execCommand command but I do not like the 0-7 px limit because I need a unit of measure in percentage.

So I decided to use execCommand with insertHTML and wrap the selection.

With chrome the result is positive while firefox behaves strangely.

I do not know if this depends on how to select or how to enter the font size ...